# Undefined columns selected while subsetting df

Tags: r

Let's say I have two different `df's`: `details` and `df`

**Details**:

```
header <- c("header1","header6","header3","header4","header5")
type <- c("type1","type2","type3","type4","type5")

details <- data.frame(header, type)
details
       header  type
    1 Header1 Type1
    2 Header6 Type2
    3 Header3 Type3
    4 Header4 Type4
    5 Header5 Type5
```

**DF**:

```
x <- c("test","test","test")
header1 <- x
header2 <- x
header3 <- x

df <- data.frame(header1,header2,header3)
df
  header1 header2 header3
1    test    test    test
2    test    test    test
3    test    test    test
```

Now I want to join them keeping what's in both of them, so it would come out like this:

```
  header1 header3
1 test    test
2 test    test
3 test    test
```

I've tried to do this:

```
df <- df[details$header]
```

but I get this error message:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(df, details$header) : undefined columns selected

What could i do to create a new df keeping only the columns that exist inside the `details$header`?

Comment: You have some elements that are not in the 'df' column names `df[intersect(names(df), as.character(details$header))]
`

Answer (score 0):

The error is mainly due to elements in 'header' column of 'details' that are not the column names.  To make it work, use `intersect`

```
df[intersect(names(df), as.character(details$header))]
#    header1 header3
#1    test    test
#2    test    test
#3    test    test
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 df[names(df)%in%details[,1]]# df[names(df)%in%details$header]
  header1 header3
1    test    test
2    test    test
3    test    test
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.